# Interface, interligação de camadas

Tags: interface

O uso da interface se dá apenas na interligação de camadas? sempre que desejo comunicar por exemplo a camada `model` com a `presenter`, vou precisar de uma interface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> O uso da interface se dá apenas na interligação de camadas?

Você pode usar interfaces entre as camadas se você quiser manter um baixo acoplamento/dependência entre as camadas. Mas o uso não está limitado apenas para isso.

Exemplo de outra utilização: Você pode definir propriedades, assinatura de métodos e eventos em sua interface, para que ela seja implementada em diferentes objetos conforme sua necessidade.

Para ilustrar, suponha que dois bancos (objetos BancoA e BancoB) precisam aplicar um desconto (comportamento comum aos dois objetos: aplicar desconto), mas o cálculo do desconto é diferente em cada objeto.

Uma vez que os objetos BancoA e BancoB implementem uma interface com esse comportamento, você pode definir uma Interface, que será um contrato que cada objeto pode implementar/definir sua própria fórmula de cálculo do desconto.

Interface:

```
interface IPagamentoDesconto
{
    double AplicarDesconto(double valor);
}
```

Classe que implementa a interface IPagamentoDesconto:

```
public class BancoA : IPagamentoDesconto
{
    public double AplicarDesconto(double valor)
    {
        //Pagamento com desconto calculado de uma forma 
    }
}

public class BancoB : IPagamentoDesconto
{
    public double AplicarDesconto(double valor)
    {
        //Pagamento com desconto calculado de uma outra forma 
    }
}
```

> sempre que desejo comunicar por exemplo a camada model com a presenter, vou precisar de uma interface?

É uma alternativa e boa prática se você quiser manter um baixo acoplamento/dependência entre as camadas *model* e *presenter*.

***Acoplamento*** significa o quanto uma classe depende da outra para funcionar. E quanto maior for esta dependência entre ambas, dizemos que estas classes elas estão fortemente acopladas. Um forte acoplamento, torna muito custoso a sua manutenção e o seu gerenciamento, pois qualquer mudança vai afetar toda a cadeia de classes.