# Como e quando usar Interface?

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, classes, interface, aplicação-desktop

Quando devo utilizar uma interface, em quais situações seu uso é viável e qual não é viável e como usá-la de maneira correta?

Desenvolvi um exemplo para ilustrar uma situação, segue abaixo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace CONTROLLER
{
    public interface InterfaceController
    {
        bool Inserir() 
        {
            //Aqui segue a rotina de inserção.
        }

        bool Alterar() 
        {
            //Aqui segue a rotina de alteração.
        }

        bool Apagar() 
        {
            //Aqui segue a rotina de exclusão.
        }
    }
}
```

A interface `InterfaceController` acima faz parte do pacote `CONTROLLER` que é onde estão as rotinas que executam operações no banco de dados, esta interface é implementa na classe *cliente* desta maneira: `public class Cliente : InterfaceController`, abaixo segue a classe `Cliente`:

```
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Text;
        using System.Threading.Tasks;
        using CONTROLLER;

        namespace MODEL
        {
            public class Cliente : InterfaceController
            {
                /*Aqui contera os atributos e os metodos de validação de regras
 *que por fim ira implementar os métodos da InterfaceController 
 *que executam operações no banco de dados.*/
            }
        }
```

A classe `Cliente` esta no pacote `MODEL` que responsável pela validações das regras de negócio, dentro da classe `Cliente` conterá os métodos de validações e os atributos que representam um cliente, entretanto, não tenho muita experiência no uso de Interfaces, não sei como usar e nem quando usar `interface`, gostaria de uma ajuda.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

É difícil dizer sem conhecer o caso concreto e principalmente sem conhecer os requisitos, as regras do negócio ou mecanismo.

## Primeiros problemas óbvios no código

Além do nome em ALL CAPS que [não segue o padrão do C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/32665/101), e o nome `InterfaceController` também não seguir, o maior problema desse código parece ser ter uma interface que determina contratos demais. A maior parte das interfaces terão apenas um método, se tiver mais que um provavelmente um é dependente do outro ou estão intimamente interligados.

Apesar de parecer estarem ligados à primeira vista, eu tenho minhas dúvidas. Novamente, depende dos requisitos que eu desconheço.

O *controller* realmente tem que ser um CRUD "completo"? Pode ser que o problema seja o nome. Nem todo *controller* deve ter estes métodos. A interface é um contrato que terá que ser obedecido, ela diz o que você precisa implementar em **qualquer** classe que faça uso dele.

O que mostra um outro erro, o código passa a impressão que se ele fosse real deveria ter um código dentro dos métodos da interface. Isto é impossível no C# atual mas antes métodos de interface só podiam ser declarados, eles não podiam ter uma implementação definida.

Outro nome que é um pouco esquisito é o da classe. Um `Cliente` deve implementar um controlador? (Veja o [princípio de Liskov](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53468/101)). Não seria melhor um controlador de um cliente implementar isso? Pode parecer bobagem, mas se não conseguir definir nomes corretos para o que cada coisa faz de fato no código fica difícil escrever um código coerente. Acho que ficaria melhor um `ClienteController`. Assim como talvez deva existir um `ClienteModel`. Este sim talvez até poderia ter o `Model` removido do nome já que uma classe cliente **pode** ser exatamente o que estaria no modelo do cliente. Mas questiono isto em várias situações.

Fica mais estranho dizer que um *namespace* chamado `CONTROLER` (não é só o *caps* que está ruim, o nome não me parece adequado também), ter "rotinas" que executam operações em banco de dados. Isto deveria ser algo contido no modelo ou até alguma coisa utilitária, externa ao MVC. O controlador deveria apenas controlar a interação entre o modelo e a visão através de requisitos provavelmente disparados pela visão. E uma classe que implementa o controlador está em um *namespace* chamado `MODEL`? Muito esquisito.

Me parece que `Inserir()`, `Alterar()` e `Apagar()` farão operações no banco de dados e não farão a ligação do modelo e visão conforme requisições, não parecem ser ações do controlador. Se for isso até faria sentido estar no modelo, ainda que nem todos gostam disto. Aí depende do ORM/DAL ou outro padrão que está usando para manipular o banco de dados (partindo do princípio que haverá um).

Mas não quero entrar muito nesse assunto aqui, porque a pergunta não é sobre MVC. Minha sugestão é estudar mais sobre MVC primeiro.

## O exemplo específico

Como o exemplo ficou bastante conturbado fica difícil falar em específico. E talvez isto esteja acontecendo por estar criando um exemplo fictício demais. Ou seja, ele não tem requisitos, aí fica difícil escrever qualquer coisa coerente, qualquer coisa poderia ser válida.

Talvez esteja querendo implementar o padrão [Repositório](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101692/101), mas precisa ver se é necessário. Pode ser que já vá usar algo que o implementa, aí é só consumir as interfaces existentes e não precisa pensar nisto tudo.

## Quando usar a interface

Pode parecer uma resposta idiota, mas é impressionante como ela é necessária para muitas pessoas: **você deve usar interface quando souber usar!** Não caia na besteira de usar por usar, porque está vendo os outros fazerem. Se não entender completamente o conceito e não souber tomar as decisões certas talvez seja melhor não sair criando interfaces. Isto vale para qualquer coisa em programação, mas vale mais ainda para códigos que existem basicamente para organizar outros códigos. Imagine o efeito contrário que pode ter usando de forma errada.

Uma coisa boa pra fazer no começo é não criar interfaces e ver quando elas são necessárias, quando há semelhanças entre classes que permitam que algo em comum possa ser definido como um contrato a ser seguido. O VS tem ajuda para fazer isto automaticamente. Basta marcar o(s) método(s) que deseja ter na interface, e pedir para extrair para ela. Depois basta colocar a declaração dela em todas classes que já implementam (s) método(s) escolhidos para fazer parte dele. Muitas vezes isto ajuda pelo menos no começo. A observação do concreto ajuda enxergar o abstrato.

Claro que isto tem a desvantagem de não obrigar o planejamento prévio, que é um dos principais motivos para se usar a interface. Criando-as faz você pensar sobre o problema que está solucionando. Mas se não tiver experiência criará coisas artificiais e sem sentido, só piorará a situação.

## Para que ela serve

Em essência interfaces devem existir quando você precisa garantir que certos tipos possuam uma determinada característica, porque esta última será necessária em algum ponto do código e com a interface você tem como dizer ao compilador que aquele tipo possui esta característica esperada. Obviamente o compilador exigirá que você implemente a interface, ele só não pode garantir que você fez da maneira correta, que cumpre tudo o que se espera. Ele só pode garantir que você escreveu alguma coisa sobre isto, que "implementou" alguma coisa na tentativa de atender o contrato.

Então qualquer método que espera receber uma interface pode receber qualquer objeto que a implemente, o compilador deixa e rejeita objetos de tipos que não fazem isto.

Interface é uma coisa do compilador pra ajudar gerar código corretos, nada mais que isto. A interface em si "desaparece" depois de compilado. A não ser que seja uma interface moderna que permite implementação de código, aí claro que a implementação não desaparece.

## Complemento

Sugiro fortemente fazer novos exemplos, talvez mais simples com requisitos bem pensados para praticar o uso e perguntar aqui se está certo e o que pode ser melhorado.

Não vou entrar em mais detalhes porque tem muita informação sobre interfaces de forma geral aqui no site, alguns com bons exemplos de como usá-las:

- [Em orientação a objetos, por que interfaces são úteis?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2913/101)
- [Classe Abstrata X Interface](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3603/101)
- [Interface ou Abstract?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35317/101)
- [Programar voltado para interface e não para a implementação, por quê?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86484/101)
- [Como e quando devemos usar Interface para documentar sistemas no PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100489/101)
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30399/101
- [Dúvida teórica - Interface, responsabilidade única](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/10313/101)
- [Por que os métodos implementados de uma interface não podem ser privados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/58891/101)
- [Como adicionar métodos static em interface?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40906/101)
- [Mandar parâmetros para uma interface C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/95363/101)
- [Interface vs Class - visibilidade de métodos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/63869/101)
- [Por que o C# não permite heranças multiplas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3596/101)
- [É correto afirmar que interface soluciona o problema de herança múltipla em Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89273/101)
- [Em OOP, uma interface pode ter atributos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89894/101)
- [É errado usar herança de classes para agrupar comportamentos e atributos comuns?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11594/101)
- [Quando devo usar Herança, Classe Abstrata, Interface ou um Trait?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73449/101)
- [Interface, interligação de camadas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/41734/101)
- [Diferença entre ICollection, IList e List?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/76316/101)
- [É correto dar maior preferência a composição do que herança?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11378/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: "Quando usar a interface?" Resposta: "você deve usar interface quando souber usar". Isso ajuda?

Comment: Um dia você vai saber que ajuda. Até lá corre atrás.

Answer (score 10):

> ## Quando utilizar uma interface e em quais situações seu uso é
>   viável?

**Segue algumas recomendações de utilização:**

- Quando há necessidade de fornecer funcionalidades comuns para as classes não relacionadas.
- Quando há necessidade de agrupar objetos com base em comportamentos comuns.
- Quando há necessidade de  introduzir o comportamento polimórfico às classes desde que uma classe pode implementar mais de uma interface.
- Quando há necessidade de fornecer uma visão abstrata de um modelo que é imutável.
- Quando há necessidade de criar componentes de baixo acoplamento, fácil manutenção e componentes conectáveis, visto que a implementação de uma interface é separada de si mesmo.
- Quando há necessidade de herança múltipla, uma classe pode implementar diversas interfaces.

> ## Em quais situações seu uso não é viável ou mal utilizado?

- Não faça as interfaces para uma funcionalidade específica. Uma interface deve definir a funcionalidade comum que pode ser implementada pelas classes de diferentes módulos ou subsistemas.
- Certifique-se de que a sua interface não contenha muitos métodos. Definir muitos métodos torna difícil a implementação da interface
- Mantenha suas interfaces com foco sobre o problema que você está tentando resolver e mantenha as tarefas relacionadas(métodos) em uma interface.
  Interfaces que têm várias tarefas não relacionadas tendem a ser muito difícil de implementar em uma classe.
- Uma interface que contenha tarefas não relacionadas deve ser desmembrada em outra interface.

> ## Exemplo da utilização:

```
interface IAcesso 
{ 
   void Ler(); 
   void Escrever(); 
} 
interface IComprimir 
{ 
   void Comprimir(); 
   void Descomprimir(); 
}
```

```
public class Documento : IAcesso, IComprimir
{
    #region IAcesso
    public void Ler()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Executando o método Ler da classe Documento para IAcesso");
    }
    public void Escrever()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Executando o método Escrever da classe Documento para IAcesso");
    }
    #endregion // IAcesso
    #region IComprimir
    public void Comprimir()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Executando o método Comprimir da classe Documento para IComprimir");
    }
    public void Descomprimir()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Executando o método Descomprimir da clase Documento para IComprimir");
    }
    #endregion // IComprimir
}
```

> ## Comentário:

Com base nos conceitos expostos,  e utilizando o exemplo da pergunta como exemplo, podemos deduzir:

A interface `InterfaceController` não possui comportamento comuns a suas classes de modelo, talvez seria melhor implementado por uma classe de acesso a dados. (É apenas opinião sem conhecer o cenário concreto)

> **Fonte:** http://www.macoratti.net/14/04/c_intf1.htm

Comment: Esta resposta procura responder de fato a pergunta, listando quando usar e quando não usar. (Isso tirando um ou outro ponto que, por não ser acompanhado de evidências, fica difícil de assimilar (fica parecendo opinião).

Comment: Gostei da sua opinião, vou procurar exemplificar alguns pontos para melhorar a resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Um exemplo prático do uso de interface:

Imagine o seguinte cenário: você tem um sistema que emite cupom fiscal. No entanto sabemos que existem várias marcas e modelos de impressoras fiscais (tomemos como exemplo, Epson, Daruma e Bematech). Todas elas tem seus comandos particulares para realizarem tarefas semelhantes entre si. Aí você precisa implementar um código no seu sistema para controlar e fazer essas chamadas a fim de realizarem a mesma tarefa em 3 impressoras diferentes, porém cada chamada de função é específica em cada uma delas.

Aí entra a necessidade de usar Interface.
Você cria uma interface com os métodos de todas elas, unificando os nomes dos métodos. Digamos que exista um método para imprimir uma linha no cupom (ImprimirLinha). Agora você terá que criar uma classe para cada impressora HERDANDO da interface seus métodos, e você então colocará em cada métodos a chamadas específica de cada impressora para aquela tarefa a que o método se destina.

No exemplo anterior, haverá um método ImprimirLinha na classe Epson, na classe Daruma e na classe Bematech e cada um deles chamará o método correto de cada fabricante, conf o manual de cada uma.

Feito isto, você criará uma Classe-pai chamada, por exemplo, ImpressoraFiscal e nela haverá o método ImprimirLinha (note que no seu sistema ele será ImprimirLinha independente do que faça lá dentro e de qual impressora seja, é transparente para quem programa e consome a classe). Nesta mesma classe-pai haverá um método NEW que cuidará do instanciamento dela própria, e receberá um parâmetro de identificação de qual impressora será usada. É ali que você criará um objeto interno comum e dependendo de qual impressora vier sinalizada, este objeto será = NEW clsEpson ou NEW clsDaruma ou NEW clsBematech.
Compreendeu? Desta forma, é transparente para quem consome a classe-pai, que comportará uma das 3 impressoras.

Dim oImpressoraFiscal = New ImpressoraFiscal("Epson")
oImpressoraFiscal.ImprimirLinha(...)

Este é o caminho correto, ao invés de criar uma classe com o método ImprimirLinha e dentro colocar "If impressora=Epson then... elseif impressora=Daruma then...", isso é totalmente inadequado.