# Problema de Cast

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, cast

Eu tenho as seguintes classes:

```
public class Hotran {

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String codEmpresa;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String nomeEmpresa;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Long voo;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String equipamento;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private List<String> diasDeVoo;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Long quantidadeAssentos;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String numeroHotran;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Date dataSolicitacao;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Date dataVigencia;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String naturezaOperacao;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Long numEtapa;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String codOrigem;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String aeroOrigem;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String codDestino;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String aeroDestino;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Date horaPartida;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Date horaChegada;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String equipAlterado;

    public Hotran() {
        this.diasDeVoo = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
```

Com a subclasse

```
public class HotranComParecer extends Hotran{

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String hotranAnt;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String cgna;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String infraero;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String gatr;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String ggco;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String ggfs;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String ggip;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String ggof;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String ggta;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String gopi;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String gopd;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String consolidacao;
```

Tenho o seguinte método:

```
private Hotran toBasicos(Row row) {
        Hotran hotran = new Hotran();
        for (Cell cell : row) {
            switch (cell.getColumnIndex()) {
            case 0:
                hotran.setCodEmpresa(PlanilhaUtil.toString(cell));
                break;
            case 1:
                hotran.setNomeEmpresa(PlanilhaUtil.toString(cell));
                break;
            case 2:
                hotran.setVoo(PlanilhaUtil.toLong(cell));
                break;
            case 3:
                hotran.setEquipamento(PlanilhaUtil.toString(cell));
                break;
            case 4:
                hotran.getDiasDeVoo().add(PlanilhaUtil.toString(cell));
                break;
            case 5:
                hotran.getDiasDeVoo().add(PlanilhaUtil.toString(cell));
                break;
            case 6:
                hotran.getDiasDeVoo().add(PlanilhaUtil.toString(cell));
                break;
            case 7:
                hotran.getDiasDeVoo().add(PlanilhaUtil.toString(cell));
                break;
            case 8:
                hotran.getDiasDeVoo().add(PlanilhaUtil.toString(cell));
                break;
            case 9:
                hotran.getDiasDeVoo().add(PlanilhaUtil.toString(cell));
                break;
            case 10:
                hotran.getDiasDeVoo().add(PlanilhaUtil.toString(cell));
                break;
            case 11:
                hotran.setQuantidadeAssentos(PlanilhaUtil.toLong(cell));
                break;
            case 12:
                hotran.setNumeroHotran(PlanilhaUtil.toString(cell));
                break;
            }
        }
        return hotran;
    }
```

Ao tentar fazer:

```
HotranComParecer hotran = (HotranComParecer) toBasicos(row);
```

Tenho o seguinte erro:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.roknauta.alure.model.Hotran cannot be cast to com.roknauta.alure.model.HotranComParecer
```

Alguém pode me ajudar por favor ?

Comment: `HotranComParecer` é subclasse de `Hotran`. Você está tentando fazer cast de uma superclasse(Hotran) para uma subclasse(HotranComParecer), e isso não é possível. Explicando de forma simples: ***"Um filho herda todo o comportamento do pai, mas o pai pode não possui todo o comportamento do filho".***

Comment: @Articuno me é confuso isso. Já que o HotranComParecer é filho ele não pode receber o pai que é Hotran ?

Comment: Não. Releia minha frase. Você não pode converter a classe mais "alta" para a "mais baixa", pois a mais "baixa" pode possuir comportamentos que a "mais alta" não faz ideia, o que torna o cast impossivel.

Comment: @Articuno agora fez sentido, tem alguma dica de como posso contornar isso ? Fiz assim porque vou usar mais 3 filhas e queria aproveitar este bloco.

Comment: Talvez [programar orientado a interfaces](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107524/28595)

Comment: @Articuno consegui criando um método void.